# How to search element by some keyword?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

**View**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>user/category" method="post">
<label>Hr</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="hr"/>
    <label>Developer</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Developer"/>
    <label>Designer</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Designer"/>
<label>CEO</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="CEO"/>
<label>Developer/Designer</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Developer,Designer"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

**Model**

```
 function category($data){
            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from("data");
            $this->db->where_in('profile',$data);
            $query =  $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }
```

**Controller**

```
function category(){
    $details =$this->input->post('check');
    if(!isset($details)){
        $this->Ulogin();
    }
    else
    {
     $details =$this->input->post('check');
    // var_dump($details);
    $data = $this->user_model->category($details);
    var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

When I search for single string like `developer/designer`, it is working but its not returning string whose profile column like `developer`,`designer`. I want
when I search for developer it should return whose profile is `developer` or `developer`,`designer` both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like query

```
$this->db->like('keywords',$keywords);
$this->db->where("condition","condition");
$query = $this->db->get("tbl_name");
```

Comment: keyword is column name here or something else,Can you explain your ans.i don't understand

Comment: what i have to write in condition

Comment: it's not compulsory ..you can remove it. .......... condition like ex. where("status","active")

Comment: $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("data");
        $this->db->like('profile',$data);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();     when i do like this i got error in query_builder  Array to string conversion  Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 972

Comment: What is content in . $data variable?

Comment: thanx its working after implode to array by comma seperator

Comment: ur ans gave me better result thanx again